# Stochastic Gradient Descent Batch Size effects

Tags: optimization, stochastic-processes, convex-optimization, intuition, machine-learning

I am trying to understand stochastic gradient descent used for residues with norm 2. Let's say we are trying to minimize $||Ax − b||^2_2$. Now we need to decide on a batch size and epoch lenght. Batch size is the number of rows of x we try to calculate per epoch. So for mini batch size 1, for each epoch, we want to solve $a_i^Tx=b_i$.

However, I am really confused about this part. What I understand intuitively is the data vectors are the rows of A and we want good x's, weights, to "move" those a's as close as possible to b's. When we decide on a batch size, for example 1, do we mean A is just a row vector with only 1 data for each epoch and and picked randomly? So a is just a random row from A? And what happens when we increase the batch size? Let's say our batch size is 2, is $a$ a $2xn$ matrix now, because each epoch we need to deal with 2 data vectors? And how x is changed accordingly to change of batch size? I really don't understand the effects of setting a batch size mathematically, I want to develop it further than mere intuition. 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have understood it wrong. S.G.D works the following way:

Let's say you have $m$ examples and Loss is MSE,
$$\
L(w) = \sum_{i=1}^m (w^Tx_i +b - y_i)^2 \quad \text{where } w,b \text{ parameters to be learnt}
$$
Let's see what the gradient looks like w.r.t $w$,
\begin{align}
\nabla_w L=2\sum_{i=1}^m (w^Tx_i +b - y_i)x_i
\end{align}
We see that we may have to sum over a lot of values of large $m$ to compute just the gradient. Remember we have to calculate the gradient in each iteration of Gradient Descent. To make it faster, we rather compute stochastic gradient:
$$\
\tilde\nabla_w L=\sum_{i=1}^B (w^T\tilde x_i +b - \tilde y_i)\tilde x_i
$$
where $\tilde x_i = x_j$ and $\tilde y_i = y_j$ for a random $j$ and $B$ is the Batch Size. Randomness is there just to make sure that stochastic gradient is unbiased i.e. $E[\tilde\nabla_w L]=\nabla_w L$. Other than this, you proceed like Gradient Descent.

**Note:** By each iteration of G.D I mean epoch. In each epoch, you compute the Stochastic Gradient. Some sophisticated methods like SVRG compute a full gradient once in between many epochs in order to reduce the variance.

Comment: So, with your example, when we pick bath size to be 1 and epoch to be 100, for each epoch we only calculate this $(^_+−_)^2$ in each epoch. And for the first iteration we have an initial w and b and then we update it in a recursive matter? And when we increase the batch size to 2, there are two elements in the summation instead of 1 and this gives us a better estimation? Did I got it this time?

Comment: Yes exactly. Btw, formulae for gradient is bit wrong in the comment. I guess that is typo.

Comment: Yes, I mistyped it! Thank you! And for my example, what happens when we want to minimize least squares, do you know? Because the function isn't defines as a sum, it's just $||−||^2\_2$. Why do we want to solve for $a^T_ix=b_i$. So maybe it doesn't change at all when batch size is 2?

Comment: @Xia The example which I used to explain is the same least squares. Note that what I regarded as $x_i$ is Indeed your $a_i$. Try to expand $\|Ax-b\|^2$. You will get the exact same form as I used. Note the $m$ is number of samples and is equal to number of rows in $A$.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!